# how to convert this declaration of byte from java to c#?

Tags: c#, java, byte

in java this return a string "-128" ;

```
   byte[] remaining = new byte[total- entred];
    remaining[0] = (byte)0x80;
```

how to write this in c# ? the (byte)0x80; seems not working in c#

Comment: What is "not working"? You want it to be -128? You can use `sbyte`.. but `sbyte` is really really rare in C#. Most likely you just have to get used to the unsignedness of bytes in C#.. (that's actually a good thing though, saves a lot of silly `& 0xFF`'s)

Answer (score 3):

In java, bytes are signed. So in C#:

```
sbyte[] remaining = new sbyte[total- entred];
remaining[0] = unchecked((sbyte)0x80);
```

or simpler:

```
remaining[0] = -128;
```

Frankly, though, it usually makes more sense to talk about `byte` (unsigned) than `sbyte`. In the java code, it is probably using signed bytes because *that is what it has available to it*, not because it actually wants to work with signed bytes.